# How to always escape user's input?

Tags: environment-variables, escaping, tcsh

I have code which creates tcsh scripts "on the fly". The code (written in Java if it matters) gets a configuration file, parses it and then creates a tcsh script out of it. In the configuration file, there is a string that has two roles in the output tcsh script:

1. Print the command (with `echo`, meaning `echo <string>`)
2. execute the command (meaning `<string>`).

The code:

```
# Java code but it really does not matter
fw.write("echo '" + cmd + "'\n");
fw.write(cmd + "\n");
```

There is a problem with the `cmd`. For the purpose of explaining the issue, consider the following cmd:

```
/run/some/setup -o1 option1 -option2 '$SOME_ENV_2_EXEC -option3 hi'

# You get:
# echo /run/some/setup -o1 option1 -option2 '$SOME_ENV_2_EXEC -option3 hi'
# /run/some/setup -o1 option1 -option2 '$SOME_ENV_2_EXEC -option3 hi'
```

If the `cmd` contains `'` then it will split it in three parts (first part is `'/run/some/setup -o1 option1 -option2 '`, second part is `$SOME_ENV_2_EXEC -option3 hi` and third part is `''`. I also can't use `"` because I will get the same error if users will use `"` in the string. I also don't want to use without quotes because I don't want to evaluate the input. For example if we have `/run/some/setup -o1 $SOME_ENV_2_EXEC`, I don't want it to evaluate `$SOME_ENV_2_EXEC`, I want it to print the env name (You get this effect with `'`: `echo '/run/some/setup -o1 $SOME_ENV_2_EXEC'` but as we saw, we get a problem if the string itself contains `'`).  How can I always make it work?

Bottomline, I want it to work for:

```
/run/some/setup -o1 option1 -option2 '$SOME_ENV_2_EXEC -option3 hi'
/run/some/setup -o1 option1 -option2 "hi"
/run/some/setup -o1 $SOME_ENV_2_EXEC
```

which workaround I can use here?